# Getting a Client Key in Microsoft Azure speech services

Tags: r, azure, cloud

I am working in R (RStudio) and need to translate a lot of text automatically. I have identified that this can be done using a packaged called translateR. To do this I need however a microsoft.client and microsoft.client.secret as specified by the main formula in the package. However, I have been unable to figure out how to get this, even though I have an Azure account and have figured that I need to sign up [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Speech/how-to/how-to-authentication?tabs=Powershell). Does anyone has experience with obtaining such keys/IDs?

EDIT:

Below @ThDataGuy links to a great guide to how to get the key. However, upon getting the two keys/IDs, I however run into another problem. Getting an error as follows

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
   Could not resolve host: datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net
```

And I have not been able to find out where it comes from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to your Azure Portal and create an app. This will provide the components you need.

[This tutorial](https://www.netiq.com/communities/cool-solutions/creating-application-client-id-client-secret-microsoft-azure-new-portal/) gives a step by step guide

Comment: I would probably never have found that. Thanks so much @TheDataGuy!

Comment: see Edit for new info. I got the client IDs, but ran into another problem!

Comment: If my previous response answered your question, then please mark as answer and refer to it in your edit. This will be beneficial to all. As for your edit, are you behind a firewall? Doing this on an intranet?